# How to add canvas to empty layout(linear or relative)

Tags: android

I have two layouts, first layout contains some textviews and other views and second layout which is inside first layout is empty, I want to add canvas to second layout and add some bitmaps and texts over that canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can add only `View`s to the layout. You can't add canvas.
But every `View` has it's canvas. What you can do is create your own custom class

```
public class MyCanvasView extends View {
...
}
```

Override it's `protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {`, and draw on it's `Canvas`:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   // Draw the shadow
   canvas.drawOval(
           mShadowBounds,
           mShadowPaint
   );

   // Draw the label text
   canvas.drawText(mData.get(mCurrentItem).mLabel, mTextX, mTextY, mTextPaint);

   // Draw the pie slices
   for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); ++i) {
       Item it = mData.get(i);
       mPiePaint.setShader(it.mShader);
       canvas.drawArc(mBounds,
               360 - it.mEndAngle,
               it.mEndAngle - it.mStartAngle,
               true, mPiePaint);
   }

   // Draw the pointer
   canvas.drawLine(mTextX, mPointerY, mPointerX, mPointerY, mTextPaint);
   canvas.drawCircle(mPointerX, mPointerY, mPointerSize, mTextPaint);
}
```

And then add it to your layout.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)